# Updating redux state does not trigger re-render (nor does it update the state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm pretty new to Redux and i'm encountering some problems with it.

I'm creating a list of items in a component, sending it to redux state and then i want to read from that redux state and display the items in a different list component.

The creation part works as i can `console.log` and `getState()` without problems (i am seeing the changes in Redux State).

My problem is that my component state does not change, nor does it re-render.

And now some code ->

```
this.state = {
    initialItems: this.props.SharepointItems,
}
```

And at the end

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        SharepointItems: state.listItems,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SharePointList);
```

I even tried something like this in my `componentDidMount()` ->

```
    store.subscribe(() => {
        this.setState({ initialItems: this.props.SharepointItems });
        console.log("updating state");
    });
```

From what i've read i shouldnt need to update the state manually while using redux, or am i wrong?

EDIT: Since my list doesnt throw an error if i `console.log` i can see that the array is empty (which is what i defined in the Redux state). Is there something that i should be doing to get the new state ? Seems like its getting the immutable state or something like that (the empty array).

Edit2: Found the problem (or part of it). It appears as my state is 1 event behind. So redux contains the array with 4 items, the component state is empty. If i do a dispatch from the browser i get 5 items (as expected) in redux, but 4 in state (it finally shows not empty).

Also my code was a bit bugged (i was passing the entire array instead of items in the array).

I've changed it to

```
        result.map((item) => {
            store.dispatch(addListItem(item));
        });
```

And it started rendering. The problem is it displays items from 0 to 2 (4 in array), but the last one is left behind. Once again if i do another dispatch from the browser i get item 3 rendered, but 4 (the last one added) is only in redux state and does not update the list state.

Also...is it a good idea to do it like this? My list might have 1000 items in the future and i'm not sure that dispatch is a good solution (i need to make an API call to get the items first, which is why i'm using dispatch to populate redux).

Updated with reducer ->

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_LISTITEM:
            return { ...state, listItems: [...state.listItems, action.payload] };
        case ADD_SPOTOKEN:
            return { ...state, spoToken: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Found something else thats a bit weird. I am also using React Router. As i said my list displays only 3 of the 4 items in my Redux State array. If i navigate to a different page and then back to the list page it actually renders all 4 of the items.

Comment: How are you triggering a state change? I can't see any dispatch?

Comment: I've updated my question. Dispatch is in a different component, but i added it.

Comment: What's your `addListItem` reducer like?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Can you log your state in mapStateToProps to see if this changes after getting dispatched.

Comment: You don't need to `store.subscribe()` in a `connect()`ed component, and you shouldn't "fork the state" by copying from `props` into `state`.

Comment: `subscribe` was more for me to see if changes are seen by Redux. I'm passing props to state because i need to change the items on that list component, but still have the default (full) list added in Redux. I'm sorting (removing items) and other things which means i need a state which can be changed by something other than items update. @Abhishek  what do you mean by log it in mapState...  ? Adding a console.log there does not trigger it. Or did i understand this wrong ( `console.log(state)`.

Comment: `mapStateToProps` runs when your store states changes.

Comment: My bad, webpack watch forgot to update the code again. If i `console.log(state)` in `mapStateToProps` i am getting the full array (exactly like  in the redux state) so it seems to work fine, but my props are still 1 item behind.

Comment: Apparently If i force a re-render of the component the props are fine (by navigating to another page with react router and back to the list page for example).

Comment: Every dispatch should call your mapStateProps. I've different code, and I use `mapDispatchToProps` inside `connect`. Can you host code somewhere?

Comment: `mapStateProps` gets called 5 times. On first load (array empty) and each time i do a dispatch for my 4 items so it seems fine. Unfortunately i can't provide a working sample. The app is too lengthy and it depends on authentication for the list items so it would be useless to create an example.

Comment: console.log(this.props.SharepointItems) and check

Comment: The props (SharepointItems) contains the full array (4 items), but my state only contains 3 of them. That's where the inconsistency happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this by mistake. I was planning on leaving it for the end and find a workaround for it, but i somehow fixed it.

I was importing the list component (which had the redux state props) in a Page (react-router). The page wasn't connected since it wasn't ready yet. Apparently after connecting the page (parent component which holds the list) everything works fine and i can see all 4 of my items (instead of seeing 3 without having the parent connected).

I wonder if this is intended...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from the fact that you have "forked" `SharepointItems` off of `props` and set it to the component's local `this.state`. Unless you *really* need to, I'd recommend not doing that. Just use `this.props`. [Dan Abramov (author of Redux) recommends this as a general principle too](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/979520339968516097?lang=en).

By forking props onto state, you create two sources of truth regarding the state of `SharepointItems`, namely, `this.state.initialItems` and `this.props.SharepointItems`. It then becomes your responsibility to keep `this.state` and `this.props` in sync by implementing `componentDidUpdate` (that is why you're not seeing it update). You can avoid all the extra work by just using the data that flows in from `props`.

The `connect` function will re-render your component with new `props` whenever you update the `redux` store. So in your `render` method, just refer to `this.props.SharepointItems` and not `this.state.initialItems`. Then you should be good to go, that is, assuming you've implemented your reducer(s) and store configuration properly.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use the props directly. As i said in the comments above i need to have a state which i modify (filter items, remove items, concat information), but i still want the default list available in redux.What exactly should i use in `componentDidUpdate` ? Do i simply set the state with new props or?

Comment: @DanteR. Any chance we could get a link to the code, like in a GitHub gist or CodeSandbox?

Comment: Not possible as i said previously. The app itself is a bit big and sharing more code would be useless since you wouldnt have access to the items themselves (authorization required). 

My problem is that after my component loads i will modify the initial state (Lets say i get the array in initialItems, to prepare for sorting i modify the initialItems state and created sortedItems which i use in my list). sortedItems stays behind because props load slower than my functions.

Comment: @DanteR. It would be really helpful if you could share the component file, or at least a trimmed down version containing only the lifecycle and render methods

Comment: That i can do, but you wont be able to demo it unless you create the items array manually. https://github.com/Taerarenai/SOQ/blob/master/Slist.jsx